# Is the Windows message queue handle the message in an FIFO way?

Tags: windows, winapi, message, message-queue

I assume when we call [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) & [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx), the message will be handled in the same order as the `Send/PostMessage` called. But as the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) says the `SendMessage` will execute the function if the current thread is the correct one.

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window
>   procedure is called immediately as a subroutine.

So in following case:

```
PostMessage(currentThreadWindow, postMsg, ...) // line 1
SendMessage(currentThreadWindow, sendMsg...) // line 2
```

the `sendMsg` will be handled before `postMsg`.

So does message passed to `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` keep the order?

Comment: You already gave an example where the order is not maintained. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, So is there any detail comments about the order of message been handled? We have a lot of logical depends on the order. For example, if the poster is not the target thread itself, will the order been kept.

Comment: If you are crossing threads, you get even less guarantees. The messages of your example could be received in either order. The only guarantee you get is, that low-priority messages will be dispatched, if there aren't any higher-priority messages in the message queue.

Comment: Is this the common message queue implementation? I see a lot of project using the message queue to queue the task in the similar way as the GCD in iOS platform. So if the message queue cannot guarantee the order, most of logical doesn't works.

Comment: A system built on a contract that doesn't exist is fragile. I'm not sure what you are after.

Comment: If you need the order, use ``std::queue<>`` or so to have your own in-order queue and use the windows message queue more as a queue state signaling mechanism. Either way, if you rely too much on the order, there is something wrong in the design. If your environment or use cases change later on it will get less and less likely that you won't get into trouble with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So does message passed to `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` keep the order?

You already know the answer to this question, if you are sending/posting a message to a window owned by the calling thread: The call to `SendMessage` bypasses the message queue altogether, and calls the window procedure immediately, so this message will always be handled prior to a posted message.

If you are crossing thread boundaries, you don't get any guarantees anymore. Even though in-bound cross-thread messages are dispatched before any messages currently in the message queue, you cannot control when the calling thread gets preempted. If it gets preempted in between the calls to `PostMessage` and `SendMessage`, the posted message is likely to be handled before the sent message. If the calling thread doesn't get preempted in between those calls, you still don't get any guarantees. It depends on the concurrently executing receiving thread, whether the posted or sent message is handled first.

To complicate things further, a thread can receive messages at other times as well (see [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)). While waiting for the result of an out-bound `SendMessage`-call, a thread will still receive in-bound cross-thread messages. In other words: You cannot even rely on the fact, that messages are handled as a whole, before moving on to the next message. Your window procedure needs to be prepared for re-entrancy.

What you can rely upon is, that the relative order of several posted messages is maintained. If you post 2 messages the first of those messages is handled prior to the second message. Those messages can still be interspersed with other posted messages.